# How to subtract the elements in a nested list in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a nested list(the sublists will only have 2 elements), like this:

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,2]]
```

I want to subtract the elements inside each nested list, like this should be the output:

```
[-1,1]
```

To sum the numerals in the nested list, I only had to use:

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,2]]
store = []
for x in list_1:
    store.append(sum(x))
```

but in subtracting since I couldn't any function like 'sum' for subtracting on the internet, I tried create one like this:

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,2]]
store = []
def subtraction(z,l):
    total = z - l
    return total
for y in list_1:
    store.append(subtraction(y))
```

but it returned:

```
TypeError: subtraction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'l'
```

How can I get over this error and also make my code work?

Comment: `store.append(sum(list_1))`: do you mean `store.append(sum(x`))` instead?

Comment: @Evert yes, sorry I am editing it

Comment: Are your sublists always going to be two elements? What behaviour do you expect for less than or more than two elements?

Comment: `store.append(subtraction(*y))`

Comment: @khelwook, yes only 2 elements

Comment: Then why not `store.append(y[0]-y[1])` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Extended Iterable Unpacking** operator.

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,2]]
store = []
def subtraction(z,l):
    total = z - l
    return total
for y in list_1:
    store.append(subtraction(*y))
```

Another way is to use `list comprehension`.

```
list = [a-b for a, b in list]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using the list comprehension

```
store = [ l1-l2 for l1, l2 in list_1]
```

Answer (score 1):

The way I would go about it is:

```
list_1 = [[1,2],[3,2]]
store = []
for a, b in list_1:
    store.append(a - b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0] - x[1], list_1))
```

**Demo**:

```
>>> list_1 = [[1,2],[3,2]]
>>> list(map(lambda x: x[0] - x[1], list_1))
[-1, 1]
```